# Check if a cookie exists on another domain

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

I have actually set the following cookie for the following domain:

```
setcookie("thing", $data, time()+3600, "/", "example1.com", 1);
```

The cookie was set from this domain: example2.com

When I try to search for the cookie 'thing' I can't seem to find it. How is it possible to set a cookie on a domain, which will remain on another domain if I search for it?

UPDATE:

I basically want to pass a value from Domain A to Domain B. When a visitor arrives to Domain A he/she gets redirected AND pass a value to Domain B which I'd like to capture there.

How is it possible?

Comment: I should hope this is not possible.  Browsers should know better than to allow Domain A to access the cookies for Domain B.

Comment: Try to use a memcache server :-)

Comment: imagine the fun people could have if `nastysite.ru` could set/get cookies for `bankofamerica.com`.

Comment: IS there anything what I can pass which identifies that I came from another domain, when I got redirected?

Comment: sure, you can embed whatever you want in the redirect url. but you can NOT use cookies

Comment: @user1406071: It's not clear what you're trying to do.  Define "came from another domain."  If you're performing a redirect then I imagine you could add anything you want to the query string, for example.

Comment: I'm updating my first post!

Comment: I wonder how this works... http://www.networkadvertising.org/choices/ I suppose it's just a company that others use. Not sure. But just found it interesting and maybe relevant.

Comment: Updated the first post, please read!

Comment: Use subdomains instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain

Answer (score 3):

Every browser prevents it.

Cookies can not be shared between domains.
https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-Origin-Policy

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it is impossible to create a cookie for another domain - this would be a pretty significant security hole.

See @scones' link.