# Share cookies between subdomain and domain

Tags: http, cookies, subdomain

I have two questions. I understand that if I specify the domain as `.example.com` (with the leading dot) in the cookie that all subdomains can share a cookie.

Can `subdomain.example.com` access a cookie created in `example.com` (without the `www` subdomain)?

Can `example.com` (without the `www` subdomain) access the cookie if created in `subdomain.example.com`?

Comment: Yes you can.. please see link below http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_internet/article.php/c19417/Sharing-Cookies-Across-Domains.htm

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089199/can-subdomain-example-com-set-a-cookie-that-can-be-read-by-example-com

Comment: can you please look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38351769/path-attribute-of-cookie-is-not-affecting-for-subsequent-requests

Comment: @adam0101 What if domain and sub domain are hosted on different server ?

Comment: @user3782114, it doesn't matter if they are on different servers. In my case, they were not only on different servers, but each domain was load-balanced across multiple servers. One thing that did trip us up a bit was that the lower environments (dev, test, uat, etc) started sharing the same cookie too once we did this because we had named them like "dev.oursite.com", "test.oursite.com", etc.. The trick there (at least in .Net) is to have a separate machine key generated for each environment and save that in your Web.config (assuming you transform the config for each environment).

Answer (score 1123, accepted):

If you set a cookie like this:

```
Set-Cookie: name=value
```

then the cookie will **only apply to the request domain**, and will only be sent for requests to the exact same domain, not any other subdomains. (See [What is a "host only" cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387338/what-is-a-host-only-cookie))

Two different domains (e.g. `example.com` and `subdomain.example.com`, or `sub1.example.com` and `sub2.example.com`) can only share cookies if the `domain` attribute is present in the header:

```
Set-Cookie: name=value; domain=example.com
```

The domain attribute must [domain-match](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265#section-5.1.3) the request URL for it to be valid, which basically means it must be the request domain or a "parent" domain. So this applies for both examples in the question, as well as sharing between two separate subdomains.

This cookie would then be sent for `example.com` and **any subdomain of `example.com`**, including nested subdomains like `subsub.subdomain.example.com`. (Bear in mind there are other attributes that could restrict the scope of the cookie and when it gets sent by the browser, like `path` or `Secure`).

Because of the way the domain-matching works, if you want `sub1.example.com` and `sub2.example.com` to share cookies, then you'll also share them with `sub3.example.com`.

See also:

- [www vs no-www and cookies](http://www.phpied.com/www-vs-no-www-and-cookies/)
- [setcookie.net](https://setcookie.net): a site where you can try it out (disclaimer: developed by me, for this question)

---

A note on leading dots in `domain` attributes: In the early [RFC 2109](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2109), only domains with a leading dot (`domain=.example.com`) could be used across subdomains. But this could not be shared with the top-level domain, so what you ask was not possible in the older spec.

However, the newer specification [RFC 6265](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265) ignores any leading dot, meaning you can use the cookie on subdomains as well as the top-level domain. Some browsers will show a leading dot in developer tools to differentiate between host-only cookies and other cookies, but this is for display purposes only.

Comment: So I had two questions in my original post. Are you saying the answer is "yes" to both, but only on newer browsers?

Comment: If I set the cookie on both subdomain.mydomain.com and mydomain.com, do I have to set them as `Set-Cookie: name=value; domain=mydomain.com` on **both** domains to make them (the cookies) shared?

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't just put the leading "." on the domain for maximum compatibility with old and new

Comment: In the old standard, a cookie with `domain=.mydomain.com` is not valid for the bare mydomain.com, so the two RFCs are not compatible with each other.

Comment: The final test links are not very good. The first does not seem to work at all, since the non-prefix version always redirects to www. The second works fine, but does not show multiple cookies. You can set multiple cookies with the same name (and different subdomains) and the browser sends them all, but the script only shows one.

Comment: I think the first link was working when this was posted :-) Regarding the second issue, that is by browser design; please see [How to handle multiple cookies with the same name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056306/how-to-handle-multiple-cookies-with-the-same-name])

Comment: @adam: technically www IS a subdomain, it's a special kind of subdomain, at least from the point of view of DNS servers.

Comment: @Frank, yes I know. My comment was to clarify that my question was regarding sharing cookies between a domain and a subdomain, NOT between two subdomains.

Comment: @AlanMacdonald because security as a default is better. also maybe you have an existing site you need to shunt to a subdomain and the original site didn't use `.` so all your users would get logged out under the old spec.

Comment: I attempted to use this approach on a redirect but figured out I also needed to add a Path entry to the Set-Cookie header. 

My final header ended up looking like this: `"Set-Cookie", $"name=value; domain=mydomain.com; Path=/; Expires=<future expiry date>"`

Comment: @laurencee as with `domain`, if `path` is not specified, it defaults to the scope of the request. The default value of the `path` attribute is the "parent directory" of the current path - so if the path is `/foo/bar`, the default path is `/foo`. A cookie (with no `path` attribute) set on the path `/foo/bar` would be sent for requests `/foo/baz`, but not for requests to `/`. Setting a `path` attribute allows you to override the scope of the cookie you set. [RFC 6265 § 5.1.4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#section-5.1.4) covers the matching logic.

Comment: What if the cookie is created in sub1.mydomain.com, with the domain set to mydomain.com does sub2.mydomain.com then have access?

Comment: @shi Yes - please see the last sentence: "This can also be used to allow `sub1.mydomain.com` and `sub2.mydomain.com` to share cookies."

Comment: @cmbuckley i thought so, i am hitting a wall here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56560924/authentication-with-net-and-a-ssr-react-app

Comment: if no . some one could use afacebook.com and get all cookies as the . is not separating the wildcard

Comment: @WalterVehoeven that's not how the domain matching works - see [RFC 6265 § 5.1.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#section-5.1.3). The string `afacebook.com` does not domain-match a domain string of `facebook.com` because the last character not included in the domain string is an `a`.

Comment: I am not sure where to put this so I am choosing the comments of the accepted answer. It took long time and failed experiments to prove the above on my localhost, until it occurred to me that I should call the localhost with a dot in the name. Like "localhost.com" or something like that. Then all the "set cookies" behaviours started following the explanations written here in this answer. Hoping this might help somebody.

Comment: Will it work also if I need to make a request from x.mydomain.com to y.mydomain.com with the x.mydomain.com cookies?

Comment: @roadev yes - read the final paragraph of the post about `sub1` and `sub2` being able to share cookies.

Comment: Regardless of what everybody says, I feel the need to point out that using .example.com is a security misconfiguration, especially if your main domain contains a lot of different subdomains. Using this with a session cookie would mean sending that cookie to every subdomain the user visits, which may be leveraged by an attacker that manages to control a server with such a subdomain.

Comment: It is not a good idea to refer to this as a "security misconfiguration." Cookies, particularly those containing sensitive data, should ideally be scoped to tightest domain/path restrictions that are appropriate. Scoping across the entire domain may be a bad idea especially for a sprawling estate, but it may also be necessary. It is important to highlight the risks, and might be a good idea to re-architect to prevent any issues, but is not fair to call this a misconfiguration.

Comment: I honestly had to read the next answer down to understand what this answer is trying to say. I have no issue with bad english, but this is vague implicitive logic, with a smattering of links

Comment: @cmbuckley if I have the leading dot, in old RFC, the cookies would only be shared between subdomains but not to the domain, but in new RFC, the cookies would be shared to the domain as well. And if I don't have the leading dot, the cookies would be shared with both domain and subdomains in both RFCs. **Is this correct?**

Comment: @ADTC your second statement is not correct - if you don't have the leading dot, the cookie does not apply to subdomains in the old RFC. But per the note at the end, there are very few cases where the leading dot isn't ignored - probably only if you have to care about IE8/9, for instance.

Comment: _"if you don't have the leading dot, the cookie does not apply to subdomains in the old RFC."_ and _"there are very few cases where the leading dot isn't ignored - probably only if you have to care about IE8/9"_ Please add these in your answer, in _"A note on leading dots"_. That ought to clear up everyone's confusion. In a gist, in the old RFC, leading dot = subdomains only (no domain), no leading dot = domain only (no subdomains), and in new RFC, it doesn't matter if there's a leading dot or no leading dot, it's _**always**_ both domain and subdomains.

Comment: @ADTC the first statement is already in the answer, and whilst a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20884869/283078) led me to believe IE8/9 might behave differently, subsequent testing suggests that might not be true.

Comment: How can i set the cookie, only for a specific sub domain, I dont want all subdomains to access it ???

Comment: @YuvrajAgarkar the only way to do this would be to set a cookie from the subdomain. For example if you set a cookie on https://a.setcookie.net/, you can restrict it to that subdomain (either choose a.setcookie.net or unspecified as the domain).

Comment: @cmbuckley, it works on the a.setcookie.net tool but not on my hosted project
i get warning in frontend and the cookie does not get attached
` attempt to set cookie was blocked because it's domain attribute was invalid with regards to host url` but i'm pretty sure i have put the right url

Comment: @YuvrajAgarkar please see the part about domain-matching - when you set a cookie, the `domain` attribute must be valid. So for example you cant set a cookie from https://setcookie.net with `domain=a.setcookie.net`. Your cookie's `domain` attribute must be a substring of the `Host`.

Comment: so in this example what should be my domain 
if i set from setcookie.net with domain = `a.setcookie.net`
because a.setcookie.net is my frontend
for this domain to work should i make my frontend to a.a.setcookie.net ???

Comment: when you say host, do you mean backend host i.e. the host where i set the cookie  ? @cmbuckley

Comment: It sounds like you should ask a separate question if you’re unsure. But you should read the first link about host-only cookies.

Comment: `mydomain` doesn't work with this strategy, but `mydomain.com` does

Comment: Is it true that any subdomain can set the cookie for the top-level domain, which will then overwrite the same-named cookies for every other subdomain? Seems horribly insecure! So anyone can basically do a session-fixation attack on my subdomain, as long as there is a DNS record for their subdomain? How would someone even mitigate something like this? The cookie can change at any time!

Comment: @GregoryMagarshak in a multi-user scenario, the top-level domain should be on the [public suffix list](https://publicsuffix.org/) which prevents setting such privacy-damaging cookies.

Comment: I am talking about subdomains of a regular domain, not a top-level domain. Such as foo.geocities.com overwriting cookies on bar.geocities.com

Comment: I understand what you’re saying, and it’s the responsibility of the owner of such a service to  add it to the PSL to prevent what you describe. For instance, [setcookie.net](https://setcookie.net) is hosted at setcookie.fly.dev. I cannot set a cookie on fly.dev, because the owners of that service have [added it to the PSL](https://github.com/publicsuffix/list/pull/1015).

Answer (score 153):

Please everyone note that you can set a cookie from a subdomain on a domain.

*(sent in the response for requesting `subdomain.example.com`)*

```
Set-Cookie: name=value; Domain=example.com // GOOD
```

But you ***can't*** set a cookie from a domain on a subdomain.

*(sent in the response for requesting `example.com`)*

```
Set-Cookie: name=value; Domain=subdomain.example.com // Browser rejects cookie
```

#### Why?

According to the specifications, [RFC 6265 section 5.3.6 Storage Model](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.3),

> If the canonicalized request-host does not **domain-match** the domain-attribute: Ignore the cookie entirely and abort these steps.

and [RFC 6265 section 5.1.3 Domain Matching](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.1.3),

> **Domain Matching**
>
> A string domain-matches a given domain string if at least one of the following conditions hold:
>
> 1. The domain string and the string are identical.  (Note that both
>    the domain string and the string will have been canonicalized to
>    lower case at this point.)
> 2. All of the following conditions hold:
>
> ```
>   *  The domain string is a suffix of the string.
>
>   *  The last character of the string that is not included in the
>      domain string is a %x2E (".") character.
>
>   *  The string is a host name (i.e., not an IP address).
> ```

So `subdomain.example.com` domain-matches `example.com`, but `example.com` does *not* domain-match `subdomain.example.com`

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5258477/5407848) also.

Comment: Thanks for providing a *documented* answer that gives the RFC refs explaining exactly when browsers are supposed to accept a cookie domain, and why it's okay for "foo.domain.com" to set a cookie for "domain.com", even though it seems it would violate the "same origin policy" and could be seen as a security risk.

Comment: this how i understand it and it works local setup but once I deploy to Test environment, then cookie no longer is being set unless i remove the domain attribute, please if you can have a look at my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69865370/httponly-cookie-not-working-when-i-use-the-domain-attribute-with-a-subdomain-val

Comment: It's worth pointing out that you can set a cookie on any superdomain up to but not including the TLD. So for instance you can't use `domain=com`. This is fairly obvious, but there are a list of domains that can't be used: https://publicsuffix.org

Answer (score 51):

I'm not sure [cmbuckley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain/23086139#23086139) is showing the full picture. What I read is:

> Unless the cookie's attributes indicate otherwise, the cookie is
> returned only to the origin server (and not, for example, to any
> subdomains), and it expires at the end of the current session (as
> defined by the user agent).  User agents ignore unrecognized cookie.
>
> [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.2)

Also

```
8.6.  Weak Integrity

   Cookies do not provide integrity guarantees for sibling domains (and
   their subdomains).  For example, consider foo.example.com and
   bar.example.com.  The foo.example.com server can set a cookie with a
   Domain attribute of "example.com" (possibly overwriting an existing
   "example.com" cookie set by bar.example.com), and the user agent will
   include that cookie in HTTP requests to bar.example.com.  In the
   worst case, bar.example.com will be unable to distinguish this cookie
   from a cookie it set itself.  The foo.example.com server might be
   able to leverage this ability to mount an attack against
   bar.example.com.
```

To me that means you can protect cookies from being read by subdomain/domain but cannot prevent writing cookies to the other domains. So somebody may rewrite your site cookies by controlling another subdomain visited by the same browser. Which might not be a big concern.

Awesome cookies test site [provided by cmbuckley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain/23086139#23086139) and for those that missed it in his answer like me; worth scrolling up.

- *[Cookie Test](https://setcookie.net)*

Comment: That looks to agree with what I'm saying: unless you specify a `domain`, the cookie is only used for the request host. This means that `Set-Cookie: name=value` from `mydomain.com` won't be sent with requests to subdomains. Have a play with [this test script](http://scripts.cmbuckley.co.uk/cookies.php) too.

Comment: @cmbuckley, ok, what you said seems correct. I'll reword my answer. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Need to point out, that section 4.1.2 (first citation) is not normative...

Comment: thanks for the cmbuckley link. nice to test how it works quickly.

Comment: Upvote for pointing out the test site again.

Comment: great test site!

Answer (score 30):

Here is an example using the [DOM cookie API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie), so we can see the behavior for ourselves.

If we execute the following JavaScript code,

`document.cookie = "key=value"`

it appears to be the same as executing:

`document.cookie = "key=value;domain=example.com"`

The cookie *key* becomes available (only) on the domain *example.com*.

---

Now, if you execute the following JavaScript code on `example.com`,

> document.cookie = "key=value;domain=.example.com"

the cookie *key* becomes available to `example.com` as well as `subdomain.example.com`.

---

Finally, if you were to try and execute the following on `subdomain.example.com`,

`document.cookie = "key=value;domain=.example.com"`

does the cookie *key* become available to `subdomain.example.com`? I was a bit surprised that this is allowed; I had assumed it would be a security violation for a subdomain to be able to set a cookie on a parent domain.

Comment: This makes me wonder if there are separate specs describing the behavior of `httponly` cookies versus the kind of cookies you are creating.

Comment: The docs you posted do not agree with the statements you make. The first 2 examples are **not** equivalent (a `domain` attribute causes the cookie to work on subdomains; no such attribute does not). Leading dots are ignored at best and actively blocked at worst.

Comment: this is the best solution if you don't want to rely on host headers. I checked it and its working

Comment: When setting example.com cookie from subdomain.example.com with

`document.cookie = "key=value;domain=.example.com"`

The cookie will only appear on subdomain.example.com. It won't show up on subdomain2.example.com or example.com.

Comment: @zeroliu which browser did you test that on? That is not how it works in modern browsers. Test this at https://subdomain.setcookie.net/

Comment: @cmbuckley kindly note that the behavior on your website with chrome/firefox can be misleading. When the server sends the cookie on domain "setcookie.net", firefox/chrome set actually a cookie on ".setcookie.net". The cookie is then visible on the sub domain. Updating in the dev tools the cookie to "setcookie.net" change the visibility of the cookie. Not a issue of your site.

Comment: @NicolasLabrot as you say, that's how those browsers are choosing to show it in their dev tools - a leading dot just means it's *not* a host-only cookie. I find that [EditThisCookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg) does a better job of displaying this.

Answer (score 8):

Be careful if you are working on [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)!
If you store your cookie in JavaScript like this:

```
document.cookie = "key=value;domain=localhost"
```

It might not be accessible to your subdomain, like `sub.localhost`. In order to solve this issue you need to use *[VirtualHost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)*. For example, you can configure your virtual host with `ServerName` `localhost.com`, and then you will be able to store your cookie on your domain and subdomain like this:

```
document.cookie = "key=value;domain=localhost.com"
```

Comment: AHA! Maybe this is my issue.

Comment: On windows, you can just modify your `hosts` file and set whatever alias you want for localhost. For example, `local.mydomain.com`.

Answer (score 3):

In both cases, yes, it can, and this is the default behaviour for both [Internet Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer) and [Edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge).

The other answers add valuable insight, but they chiefly describe the behaviour in Chrome. It's important to note that the behaviour is completely different in Internet Explorer. [CMBuckley's very helpful test script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain/23086139#23086139) demonstrates that in (say) Chrome, the cookies are not shared between root and subdomains when no domain is specified.

However, the same test in Internet Explorer shows that they are shared. This Internet Explorer case is closer to the take-home description in CMBuckley's www-or-not-www link. I know this to be the case because we have a system that used different servicestack cookies on both the root and subdomain. It all worked fine until someone accessed it in Internet Explorer and the two systems fought over whose session cookie would win until we blew up the cache.